# how to install a cake 3 webapp under a different directory but same url?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a url called `http://cake.dev` and I want `http://cake.dev/cake3` to point to a cake3 web app.

I have successfully gotten the webpages to work, but all the urls pointing to various assets like base.css are wrong.

This is because the various HtmlHelpers are outputting `/css/base.css` when I need them to be `/cake3/css/base.css`

How do I change this system-wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the config/app.php

under App, you can set your 'base' to 'cake3'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will solve your problem; it's how I have overcome messy urls in the dev environment:

- create a directory in the web server's DocumentRoot, such as 'cake3'
- mount --bind path-to-my-dev-tree documentroot-url-newdirectory

where path-to-my-dev-tree is the path to the directory that contains your cake root, where the bin, etc., directories are.